github folder permissions to pull and push
I have a github repository and now i want to invite Collaborators into.
This is a huge project and i need to prevent abuse and copywriting.
Now i think have to give special permission for pulling request from repository and pushing the changes. for example i have three folder f1,f2,f3 and i want my Collaborators access to only f1 and cant see, pullign or pushing, other folders.
The other option i need to merge new pushes into current branch with review and accepting
I try to use codeowner but this is just give an access to  manage changing file, not see or etc that i need to.
I would be very happy if help me about this problem

Well there’s no way to give someone access to just one file. You either give them read access to the repo or you don’t. What you can possibly do is to give read only permission so that the unauthorized collaborator could not send the merge requests.
Btw, did you check out this link? It explains in detail the procedure to invite one or more collaborators in your project.
Also, in the same page, you would find a place linking to page listing full range of permissions you can assign to an individual collaborator.

I found a mistake way but it work for me. I added new github repo into my special folder and with codeowners I supervised on new codes
